# How to efficiently find nearest / bracketing numerical values (and do linear interpolation) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Assume that I have a database table with the contents:

| Timestamp | Position |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 900 |
| 15 | 1400 |
| 23 | 1700 |
| 24 | 1708 |

I would then want to calculate the respective `Position` for a given `Timestamp` using linear interpolation. Say, I've got a query for `Timestamp: 22`, then I'd need to fetch the next smaller and next bigger rows, which are `15, 1400` and `23, 1700`. The interpolation would then be `interpolation = ((23-22)*1400 + (22-15)*1700) / (23-15)` resulting in `1662.5`.

For a single value, I can easily get the bracketing rows and interpolate using:

```
query_time = 22
time_lower, pos_lower = session.query(Time, Position).filter(Time <= query_time).order_by(Time.desc()).limit(1).one()
time_higher, pos_higher = session.query(Time, Position).filter(Time > query_time).order_by(Time.asc()).limit(1).one()
result_pos = ((time_higher-query_time)*pos_lower + 
                  (query_time-time_lower)*pos_higher) / (time_higher-time_lower)
```

My problem is that I need to do that efficiently for a large number of queries. The database contains millions of rows and my queries are for a couple of thousand query values. That means, math and memory are no issues but sending 2000 queries for 1000 values is a lot of overhead. Also, if I could do the calculations within the database, I'd probably save (de-)serialization time and network bandwidth.

For some scenarios, I found a speedup by fetching all rows between the smallest and largest query value and then stuff them into `numpy.interp()`. This has the disadvantage that for sparse input data, I fetch lots of rows that are not needed.

Any ideas how to solve this in SQL using `SQLAlchemy` efficiently? Ideally in a way that works with SQLite, MariaDB, and PostgreSQL.

I've tried to search the web and StackOverflow for solutions, but it seems I'm using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 3):

At least three options come to mind that allow querying with multiple values in a single query in this case: scalar subqueries, using `LATERAL` joins, or window functions. `LATERAL` is the "for each" of SQL; it allows a sub-`SELECT` to refer to `FROM` items that appear before it in the `FROM` list. Window functions allow performing calculations over sets of rows that are related to the current row.

Based on guessing, I would imagine that `LATERAL` wins when the number of query values is small compared to the number of rows in the table (or the table itself is small), and `Timestamp` is indexed. The scalar subquery approach is similar, but has to perform 4 subqueries, depending on the planner, instead of 2 joins. If the number of query values is close to the number of rows in the table and spread wide, so that in order to calculate the interpolated values almost all of the table must be read, then the window function approach might take the lead.

| Feature | PostgreSQL | MySQL | MariaDB | SQLite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Scalar subqueries | x | x | x | x |
| `LATERAL` | 9.3 | 8.0.14 |  |  |
| Window functions | 8.4 | 8.0 | 10.2 | 3.25.0 |

In order to pass multiple values to query against, a "constant table" or a temporary table is needed. In PostgreSQL it is easy to create such a "constant table" using `VALUES` (or `unnest()` etc.):

```py
from sqlalchemy import values, column, Integer

# Add query values as needed to `data`
qts = values(column("ts", Integer), name="qts").data([(22,)])
```

In MySQL (before 8.0.19) and SQLite a `UNION ALL` of `SELECT` must be used instead:

```py
from sqlalchemy import literal, select, union_all

qts = union_all(*[select([literal(v).label("ts")]) for v in [22]])
```

#### Scalar subqueries

```py
lower = (
    session.query()
    .filter(Time <= qts.c.ts)
    .order_by(Time.desc())
    .limit(1)
)
higher = (
    session.query()
    .filter(Time > qts.c.ts)
    .order_by(Time.asc())
    .limit(1)
)
time_lower = lower.with_entities(Time).label("time_lower")
time_higher = higher.with_entities(Time).label("time_higher")
pos_lower = lower.with_entities(Position).label("pos_lower")
pos_higher = higher.with_entities(Position).label("pos_higher")

with_high_low = session.query(
    qts.c.ts,
    time_lower,
    time_higher,
    pos_lower,
    pos_higher
).subquery()

session.query(
    with_high_low.c.ts,
    (
        (with_high_low.c.time_higher - with_high_low.c.ts)
        * with_high_low.c.pos_lower
        + (with_high_low.c.ts - with_high_low.c.time_lower)
        * with_high_low.c.pos_higher
    ) / (with_high_low.c.time_higher - with_high_low.c.time_lower)
).all()
```

#### `LATERAL`

```py
lower = (
    session.query(Time.label("ts"), Position.label("pos"))
    .filter(Time <= qts.c.ts)
    .order_by(Time.desc())
    .limit(1)
    .subquery()
    .lateral()
)
higher = (
    session.query(Time.label("ts"), Position.label("pos"))
    .filter(Time > qts.c.ts)
    .order_by(Time.asc())
    .limit(1)
    .subquery()
    .lateral()
)

session.query(
    qts.c.ts,
    (
        (higher.c.ts - qts.c.ts) * lower.c.pos
        + (qts.c.ts - lower.c.ts) * higher.c.pos
    ) / (higher.c.ts - lower.c.ts)
).all()
```

#### Window Functions

Combine the query values and the known values, removing query values that have a known value:

```py
from sqlalchemy import null, not_, func, case

comb = session.query(
    qts.c.ts.label("ts"),
    null().label("pos")
).filter(
    not_(session.query(Time).filter(Time == qts.c.ts).exists())
).union(
    session.query(Time, Position)
).cte()
```

Build a partitioned view of the data so that it is possible to pick the lower and higher non-`NULL` values:

```py
part = session.query(
    comb.c.ts,
    comb.c.pos,
    func.count(comb.c.pos).over(order_by=comb.c.ts).label("lp"),
    func.count(comb.c.pos).over(order_by=comb.c.ts.desc()).label("hp")
).cte()
```

The above would be unnecessary, if `lag()` and `lead()` with `IGNORE NULLS` was supported.

Finally, interpolate:

```py
lw = dict(
    partition_by=part.c.lp,
    order_by=(part.c.ts, part.c.pos.nullslast())
)
hw = dict(
    partition_by=part.c.hp,
    order_by=(part.c.ts.desc(), part.c.pos.desc().nullslast())
)
fv = func.first_value
time_lower = fv(part.c.ts).over(**lw)
time_higher = fv(part.c.ts).over(**hw)
pos_lower = fv(part.c.pos).over(**lw)
pos_higher = fv(part.c.pos).over(**hw)

interp = session.query(
    part.c.ts,
    case([(part.c.pos == None,
           ((time_higher - part.c.ts) * pos_lower +
            (part.c.ts - time_lower) * pos_higher) /
           (time_higher - time_lower))],
         else_=part.c.pos).label("pos")
).cte()
```

And then pick the values of interest:

```py
session.query(interp.c.ts, interp.c.pos).filter(
    interp.c.ts.in_(qts.select())
).all()
```